# Problem with MUI form's validator min/max in inputMode numeric

Tags: reactjs, forms, validation, material-ui

I have a form with some text inputs with validators for min and max length.

In the create form I have no problem, but when I call my API and fill the form in edition, the inputs with type text but only numbers inside are marked as with **error for min or max validation**.

Is not the case for inputs with letters or letters and numbers, and is not the case for `required` validation.

I'm gonna show a short version, but I tried different things for isolate the error, and is just for numbers with those validators, even using only one (so at least is not for `isNumber` or `required`).

When I delete and rewrite the last number, the error helper disappears, the validator starts to work well. Thank you!

```
import { ValidatorForm, TextValidator } from 'react-material-ui-form-validator';
import { styled } from '@mui/system';

const TextField = styled(TextValidator)(() => ({
    width: '100%',
    marginBottom: '16px',
}));

    <ValidatorForm
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
        onError={() => null}
    >
        <Grid container spacing={6}>
            <Grid
                item
                lg={6} md={6} sm={12} xs={12}
                sx={{ mt: 2 }}
            >
                <TextField
                    type='text'
                    name='name'
                    id='name'
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    value={name || ''}
                    validators={['required']}
                    label='Nombre'
                    errorMessages={['Campo obligatorio']}
                />
                <TextField
                    type='text'
                    name='cuit'
                    id='cuit'
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    value={cuit || ''}
                    validators={[
                        'required',
                        'minStringLength:11',
                        'maxStringLength: 11',
                        'isNumber',
                        ]}
                    label='CUIT'
                    errorMessages={[
                        'Campo obligatorio',
                        'CUIT inválido',
                        'CUIT inválido',
                        'CUIT inválido',
                        ]}
                    />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
  </ValidatorForm>
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it adding `'matchRegexp:^([0-9]{11})$'` to validators instead of min and max!